# how to change my domain type from liquid to gas in the middle of my simulation so that i can change my liquid into smoke

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am thinking to change my fluid simulation liquid into smoke in the middle of the simulation is there any way for it?? i have scrolled tons of pages in the internet i didnt find any way to do it .

Comment: AFAIK - you can't. you can just fake it and make a 2nd domain and make the first invisible on one frame and the 2nd visible

Comment: Like Chris said, it's best to use a process of smoke and mirrors here. You may be able to use the last frame of your liquid phase as a starting point by converting a duplicate of it into a mesh and using that as the inflow for your smoke.